# Django Paginator Limiting Iteration of all Objects

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a standard blog on my site that I added pagination to with Django Paginator.  I also have a sidebar that iterates over all Posts and displays title and link. Everything seems to work for the most part except in `list_view` the sidebar only displays the titles and links to posts visible on the current page, but in `detail_view` all titles and links are available. I know why its doing it, I just don't understand how to fix it.

Below is a copy of my `list_view` and a couple screenshots for easier reference. Thank you.

**post_list**

```
def post_list(request, tag_slug=None):
    posts = Post.published.all()
    tag = None

    if tag_slug:
        tag = get_object_or_404(Tag, slug=tag_slug)
        posts = posts.filter(tags__in=[tag])

    paginator = Paginator(posts, 3)  # 3 posts in each page
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        posts = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        # If page is not an integer deliver the first page
        posts = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        # If page is out of range deliver last page of results
        posts = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    return render(request, 'press/post_list.html', {'page': page, 'posts': posts, 'tag': tag})
```

[image: List View]

[image: Detail View]

Comment: If you want to display more recent posts on the sidebar of the homepage than the paginated items allow, then you need to pass a different QuerySet to the template and iterate over that, instead of using the paginated `posts` object as I presume you currently are (I'm guessing, as you haven't shown the relevant parts of your templates.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send the "posts" list separately for all posts without applying paginator.  Send the paginated ones in a separate list variable such as "paginated_posts".  That way you won't be limited to the paginated posts on the right hand side.

The more optimal way I would think of doing this is send the same # of posts per page as the max number you want to show for your "recent posts", assuming you are not trying to show ALL posts in your recent posts.  If there is a happy medium for your most recent posts # to match the number of posts you want to paginate on - you are all set.

Comment: Thank you Ben and BobbyC for the response...it's the obvious solutions that slip past the brain sometimes :)  - I do agree with your 'more optimal' way, but for a small site with few posts, iterating over twice is fine, but definitely not ideal as the site and amount of posts grow larger.  Thank you.